# SAS Proc UCM ODS tables output for multiple iterations

Tags: stored-procedures, automation, sas, dataset, ods

I am trying to run multiple iterations(5400) of various combinations of predictors in Proc UCM. The SAS code with all combination of variables has been sequentially generated using an external programming code like csharp etc.

I think this can be done in SAS but thats a topic for next time.

I want to compile all the parameter estimates of all iterations into one table and all the "Smoothed estimate of sum of all components except the irregular component" into another and write some conditions on it.

Currently i am writing all the output to csv for no good.I just know i can use ODS option and specify "ParameterEstimates" and "SmoothedAllExceptIrreg" but to do it for whole 5400 iterations is something i cant figure out.

My sample code for 4 iterations is as below (1347 1348 1349 1350 are the iterations sequentially geneared based on combinations):

/*Level with variance,Season without variance,Slope without variance*/

```
ods csv file = "D:\SAS\Iteration_Hair_Care_Volume_1347.csv";
proc ucm data = project.Compiled printall;
irregular ;
level ;
forecast  lead = 8 alpha = 0.05 outfor = project.Compiled_Output_Hair;
model 
HC = 
Gr_CPI
gdp;
season length=4 
var = 0 noest;
slope 
var = 0 noest;
where count > 36;
run;
quit;
ods csv.close;



/*Level with variance,Season without variance,Slope with Variance*/
ods csv file = "D:\SAS\Iteration_Hair_Care_Volume_1348.csv";
proc ucm data = project.Compiled printall;
irregular ;
level ;
forecast  lead = 8 alpha = 0.05 outfor = project.Compiled_Output_Hair;
model 
HC = 
Gr_CPI
Earning_Avg_Lag;
season length=4 
var = 0 noest;
slope ;
where count > 36;
run;
quit;
ods csv.close;



/*Level with variance,Season with variance,Slope without Variance*/
ods csv file = "D:\SAS\Iteration_Hair_Care_Volume_1349.csv";
proc ucm data = project.Compiled printall;
irregular ;
level ;
forecast  lead = 8 alpha = 0.05 outfor = project.Compiled_Output_Hair;
model 
HC = 
Gr_CPI
pdi
season length=4 ;
slope 
var = 0 noest;
where count > 36;
run;
quit;
ods csv.close;



/*Level with variance,Season with variance,Slope with Variance*/
ods csv file = "D:\SAS\Iteration_Hair_Care_Volume_1350.csv";
proc ucm data = project.Compiled printall;
irregular ;
level ;
forecast  lead = 8 alpha = 0.05 outfor = project.Compiled_Output_Hair;
model 
HC = 
Gr_CPI
IIP;
season length=4 ;
slope ;
where count > 36;
run;
quit;
ods csv.close;
```

I can append iteration numbers to outfor dataset but i dont know what good comes out of it. How do i automate this. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I think an answer to this may be beyond what can be posted here, if you post it on communities.sas.com I'll post an answer. You can include the portion about how you needed to set up all the models if you want as well.

Comment: The question as stated to me, is very broad, which is why it may not meet SO rules.

Comment: Last example here is relevant, and if you use a naming convention it becomes a very simple process to append the data sets at the end. http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-macros-introduction/